# Is there any Prophet among Jinn?

Tags: prophets, jinn

Assalamu'alaikum,

As we know Holy Qur'an is for both Mankind, and Jinn, there are lots of warnings, and guidance for both. But is there any Warner like our Prophets among Jinn for them? If no, then don't they need any? If no, then whats the explanation of this?

Jazakallah Khair.

Comment: Does it say anywhere in the Quran that there are no Prophets among the jinns?

Comment: That wasnt said, but is there any story about Prophet among them? please enlighten me..

Comment: I mean the question says why there is no prophet among the jinn? That is why I asked if the Quran says so. You see because it isnt mentioned doesn't mean there are no prophets among the jinns. With other words it's ghayb (unknown) and we cannot know. I am not familiar to any traditional mentioning there was prophets among the jinns. But I still can't say there wasn't. Have a nice day =)

Comment: Right, i did mistake in the title, but the description was as you said. I'm correcting it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a verse in the Quran that allows the interpretation of Messengers among Jinn:

> "O company of **jinn** and mankind, **did there not come to you messengers from among you**, relating to you My verses and warning you of the meeting of this Day of yours?" ... ([6:130](http://legacy.quran.com/6/130))

One interpretation of this verse quoted by [at-Tabari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Tabari) in [his tafsir](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=50&surano=6&ayano=130) as the opinion of [Muqatil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muqatil_ibn_Sulayman) and ad-Dahhak الضحاك which is also held by ibn Hazm in his al-Muhalla is that both kinds (Mankind and Jinn) had Messengers of their own kind!
Ibn Kathir explained the verse as follows:

> ("O you assembly of Jinn and humans! Did not there come to you Messengers from among you'') We should note here that the Messengers are from among mankind only, not vice versa, as Mujahid, Ibn Jurayj and others from the Imams of Salaf and later generations have stated. The proof for this is that Allah said, ... [For more details see [qtafsir]](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=968&Itemid=61)

Those scholars are seemingly the exception as the majority of scholars say that Messengers have only been among humans based on verses such as:

> 1. And We sent not before you [as messengers] except men to whom We revealed from among the people of cities.  ... ([12:109](http://legacy.quran.com/12/109))
> 2. And We did not send before you, [O Muhammad], any of the messengers except that they ate food and walked in the markets. ... ([25:20](http://legacy.quran.com/25/20))
> 3. And We gave to Him Isaac and Jacob and placed in his descendants prophethood and scripture. ... ([29:27](http://legacy.quran.com/29/27))

and other quotes!

Answer (score 0):

Genies, like humans, have prophets of their own kind. What is well used in the verses of Surah Al-Jinn is that the Qur'an and Islam were revealed to everyone, even them, and the Prophet of Islam was sent to everyone, but there is no obstacle to the messengers and their representatives being invited by the Prophet PBUH. They have been. (1)
The Prophet of Islam, peace and blessings of God be upon him, also had contact with the jinn and offered them divine commands and duties. These matters are clearly stated in Surah Al-Jinn and verse 30 of Surah Al-Ahqaf.

The jinn considered themselves the addressees of the Qur'an and listened to it. A group of jinns pledged allegiance to the Prophet and became his representative among their tribe. Sometimes some jinns would come to the Messenger of God and ask their questions.
The pure Imams (as) also had relations with the jinn after the Messenger of God, due to the responsibility of their Imamate. When the representative of Imam Ali (as) among the jinn died, his son came to the Imam and got a homework. The Imam also replaced him with his father. It goes without saying that the relationship between the Imams and the Prophets and the jinn was not limited to these cases. Genies have more abilities than humans in some things due to the nature of their creation; Hence, the prophets and imams used their jinn friends and devotees to do difficult things.(2)

(1): Makarem Shirazi, Nasser, Tafsir Nomoneh, vol. 5, p. 443

(2)Ref: http://daneshnameh.roshd.ir/mavara/mavara-index.php?page=%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%aa%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%b7+%d8%ac%d9%86%db%8c%d8%a7%d9%86+%d8%a8%d8%a7+%d9%be%db%8c%d8%a7%d9%85%d8%a8%d8%b1+%d9%88+%d8%a7%d9%85%d8%a7%d9%85%d8%a7%d9%86&SSOReturnPage=Check&Rand=0